# R: How to traverse from root node to each leaf node in an iGraph data object and get the path?

Tags: r, graph, igraph, treenode

I am new to R and I have a graph object which I have created from a data frame object "allTog" as shown below:

```
library(igraph)
df.g <- graph.data.frame(d = allTog, directed = TRUE)
plot(df.g, vertex.label = V(df.g)$name)
```

[image]

The allTog data frame is given by

```
allTog <- data.frame(
    source = c("chamber", "chamber", "chamber", "chamber", "chamber", 
    "check", "check", "issue", "issue", "issue"), 
    target = c("check", "issue", "leak", "process", "found", "power", 
    "customer", "customer", "wafer", "replaced") 
    )
```

The columns "row.names" and "values" is of no interest here.

How can I traverse from each root node, in this case "chamber", to every leaf node and get the path i.e all the node (vertex) names? I'm looking for a generic solution because my root node can change with every run of the code. For example in the next run, the root node can be "issue".

My output that I want is:

```
chamber->check->power
chamber->issue->replaced
chamber->process
chamber->issue->customer
```

So and so forth....

Comment: It's very unclear what you want the output to be. Do you really need a transversal? It doesn't seem like you're talking along the nodes gathering any information. Also, how are you defining the root node in each cluster? Is the the node that only has incoming links? Will there always be exactly one of those? I just want to make sure I completely understand your test data. Because you are asking for paths from each leaf to each root but right now these are all exactly one edge.

Comment: The root node is being defined by a user drop down menu in a Rshiny UI. Which is why, the root node can change. There will always be only one root node. For example: in another run, the root node can be "wafer". I have edited the question as well, perhaps that will throw more light.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

How about

```
root <- "chamber"
leafnodes <- sapply(V(df.g), function(x) length(neighbors(df.g,x))==0 )
paths <- get.all.shortest.paths(df.g, V(df.g)[root], leafnodes)$res
sapply(paths, function(vs) paste(V(df.g)[vs]$name, collapse="->"))
```

This lists all the leaf nodes you can get to

```
# [1] "chamber->leak"            "chamber->process"         "chamber->found"          
# [4] "chamber->check->power"    "chamber->issue->customer" "chamber->check->customer"
# [7] "chamber->issue->wafer"    "chamber->issue->replaced"
```

Comment: good point @thelatemail I guess i missed the root-to-leaf only part. Will update.

Comment: Hey thanks for the idea. I see that there are 8 paths in this plot. But get.shortest.paths returns only 7 paths. "chamber->issue->customer" is missing. Is there anyway to get all 8 paths?

Comment: I am accepting this answer as I have decided to work with this seemingly partial output. Thank you all the help!

Comment: @user1452759 I've updated the answer to return all shortest paths from root to leaf rather than just an arbitrary one. so if there are multiple ways to get to the root to a leaf (in a minimal number of steps) then both paths with be returned so you will get both "chamber->issue->customer" and "chamber->check->customer"