# Identify all children of a certain node for very large data

Tags: r, performance, tree, igraph

I am trying to find all downstream nodes in a large graph object (~1 million edges).

In this example, I want to see all nodes that are downstream from 4:

[image]

The below code is adapted from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25758769/4650934) answer using `igraph` but it ran for over 20 minutes before I ended it. I saw the `hR` package (see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54499441/4650934)) but it also has trouble with the size of the data.

I'm new to graph analyses and not sure if there are better methods

```r
library(tidyverse)
library(igraph)

graph_df <- # real example has 1.2M connections
  make_tree(100000, children = 3)


leafnodes <- # bottleneck
  sapply(
    X = V(graph_df), 
    FUN = \(x) length(neighbors(graph_df, x)) == 0
  )


find_all_children <- function(root) {
  paths <- 
    get.all.shortest.paths(
      graph = graph_df, 
      from = V(graph_df)[root], 
      to = leafnodes
    )$res
  
  tibble(
    path = map_chr(paths, ~paste(.x, collapse = " -> "))
  )
}

# desired output
find_all_children(12)
#> 12 -> 35 -> 104 -> 311 -> 932 -> 2795 -> 8384
#> 12 -> 35 -> 104 -> 311 -> 932 -> 2795 -> 8385
#> 12 -> 35 -> 104 -> 311 -> 932 -> 2795 -> 8386

find_all_children(1234)
#> 1234 -> 3701 -> 11102 -> 33305 -> 99914
#> 1234 -> 3701 -> 11102 -> 33305 -> 99915
#> 1234 -> 3701 -> 11102 -> 33305 -> 99916
```

---

Bonus question:

Is there a `purrr` method to replace the `sapply()` here? I didn't have any luck with `map()`

Comment: Can you please explain the problem in precise terms? The one sentence you currently have isn't sufficient. It is not clear to me what you are trying to do and what you mean by "downstream nodes" or "children".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably you can try `subgraph` + `subcomponent` to prune your tree first and then find `all_simple_paths`, e.g.,

```
n <- 100000

g <- make_tree(n, children = 3) %>%
    set_vertex_attr(name = "name", value = seq(vcount(.)))

find_all_children <- function(g, root) {
    g %>%
        subgraph(subcomponent(., root, "out")) %>%
        all_simple_paths(1, V(.)[degree(., mode = "out") == 0])
}
```

and run the following lines for example

```
r12 <- find_all_children(g, 12)
r1234 <- find_all_children(g, 1234)
```

which might be done in seconds even with `n <- 100000`.

## Toy Example

```
n <- 20

g <- make_tree(n, children = 2) %>%
    set_vertex_attr(name = "name", value = seq(vcount(.)))

plot(g)
```

[image]

and we can obtain

```
> find_all_children(g, 3)
[[1]]
+ 3/7 vertices, named, from dab4822:
[1] 3  6  12

[[2]]
+ 3/7 vertices, named, from dab4822:
[1] 3  6  13

[[3]]
+ 3/7 vertices, named, from dab4822:
[1] 3  7  14

[[4]]
+ 3/7 vertices, named, from dab4822:
[1] 3  7  15
```